# public Camera cam; not working with Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am working on a game in Unity where you can interact with chests. To make this work I use the camera to detect if the player is looking at the chest or not. But i keep getting the following error:

```
NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object
PlayerInteraction.Update () (at Assets/cs scripts/PlayerInteraction.cs:22)
```

Here is the code I use for this:

```
public Camera cam;


    void Start()
    {
        cam = Camera.main;
    }

    void Update()
    {
        Ray ray = cam.ScreenPointToRay(new Vector3(Screen.width / 2f, Screen.height / 2f, 0f));
        RaycastHit hit;
    }
```

I tried changing `public Camera cam;` to `Camera cam;` but this didn't seem to change anything. I also checked if the Unity side of things here is correct but there are no issues there either.

What should i do to fix this?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: The cam object is not connected to a a camera.  Check your startup files to see if you are really making a connection to unity.

Comment: Make sure there is a `Camera` in your scene that is tagged `MainCamera` .. otherwise `Camera.main` won't find anything

Comment: @jdweng what startup files? connected to unity?

Comment: Usually it either the proj or the config file.  Sometimes it just may be hard coded in the cs file(s).  The camera constructor should contain the connection parameters.